# how to decode a flatedecode stream in c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, filter, decode

Hi I am tring to decode a flatedecode stream of a pdf file. How can I do it in c#? thanks for your answers.

What I want to do is to decode for example a stream like this:

```
    <</Filter[/FlateDecode]/Length 18446>>
stream
xœíÜ=K[aÇáã‹/qE8YÐÅ‚]¤‘b'‡
qn]Üº6ÁFJ÷
u\+ˆ[>@¶Ìš€Ål]„‚C&%ÖóNä¾®éÿóÍÃ¯~r×:Lþi”—^ž½H   €!×è~y~”×ï?ì    Ãnwfz<=
<|œßÈ{   ¹ïëoŠéû¯ŸÇó   d®ÔïUÒ[@{Ðœ­æ½   È\G0    B   €X    Á    F0    b   €X    –Ò—?Â§b¡Ñ{5ù®5:—l®ü˜,ußn½®ý®Í$ ðßÜþÚ¾¸YÜûyµzº~pÿw9ïA  Õ»j   Šš    Ä¢&    ±”ú½Jzhš³Õ¼×    ™ë   @(‚   ‹`    Ä"    Á   @,‚   ‹`    ÄrÜï5žO•öàzj"  Z#ë—­µ'ç>Q

endstream
```

Comment: it's not spam I am sorry for this long stream anyway do you have any idea ho to do it???

Comment: I am tring to  develop a software that can read a pdf  created by iluustrator and extract from it all the info about the geometric figures contained in the file. I think those information are inside the stream... can someone help me?

Comment: You need a library? Try [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com)

Comment: SharpZipLib si DotNetZip will help you with the decompression.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the clipped stream (as 18446 binary bytes, not as text seen above) then pass the clipped file through zlib-flate.

`qpdf-11.3.0-msvc32\bin\zlib-flate.exe -uncompress <fonts_woff.flate`

Different but typical "Result" on console, goes on for ages :-)

```
/GSa gs /CSp cs /CSp CS
0.750000000 0 0 -0.750000000 9.75000000 832.250000 cm
q q
Q
Q q
q
Q
q
0.960000000 0 0 0.960000000 0 0 cm
/CSp cs 0 0 0 scn
/GSa gs
0 0 0 SCN
1 w 0 J 2 M 0 j []0  d
Q
Q q
0 0 m
766.080006 0 l
766.080006 1095.71724 l
...
```

to save as a file

`zlib-flate.exe -uncompress <fonts_woff.flate>inflated.txt`

to see such a stream in context perhaps use one of the standard deflaters/inflaters

- MuPDF Mutools (not FOSS, for private use or license)
- PDFtk (exceptionally low cost for server commercial version.)
- qpdf includes above zlib-flate (FOSS usable for commercial projects)